# Maven/TestNG/Selenium - Can I set up multiple tests suites in one testng.xml and run different ones at different times?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I am using Maven/TestNG/Selenium.  I have about 50 tests in one suite and one file  right now what I want to do is separate tests into several suites:

Acceptance  - Will have the five tests to accept the build
Full Pass   - The other forty-five tests
Debug       - The one testing I am currently coding and debugging

I want to be able to run a particular suite as needed.  Can I do this from one testng.xml file or do I need multiple files?

I think my testng.xml file will look something like:

```
 <suite name="ACCEPT">
  <test name="blah">   </test>
  <test name="foo">   </test>
</suite> 

<suite name="FULLPASS">
  <test name="T1">    </test>
 <test name="T2">    </test>
 <test name="T3">    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Can you consider showing us how your `testng.xml` is structured now? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can refer other suites in suite.xml as shown [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/sharing-parameters-among-different-testng-suites/)
2. If you're using surefire you can configure execution in POM using `suiteXmlFiles` tag or by passing system property `-Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=suite.xml` like shown [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html)